# Create an email tracker

Tags: email-analytics

I thought I would find tons of information on the subject but somehow the implementation of email tracking seems to illude me on the web. I understand that there is the so-called email tracking pixel that you can add to an html email. I suppose the src attribute of this image (pixel) would point to a website action or api that would note the opening of the email, etc. However this seems too easy for there to be email services that charge a ton of money to track emails.

I need to implement my own email tracking and am wondering has anyone implemented an email tracking and what are the caveats to it? I am not looking for specific implementations in php, ruby or asp.net, although such would be more than welcomed. I am more looking for the basic principals and approaches to such an implementation.

Comment: This is why most email programs won't load external images until you click *Show Images*.

Comment: Also I read somewhere that most email services like Gmail will proxy the images. So is there a smarter way to track emails?  It does not seem to be so, but I thought to ask anyway. There are services like mailchimp, and various other that for example integrate with your CRM (SalesForce, Sugar) and they claim that they are doing it and do charge for it. So how do they do it? Or we should assume that they are not as accurate as expected?

Comment: this question looks too broad, but I am also looking for the same